# Unable to Use Stanford Semgrex in Python

Tags: python, json, parsing, pattern-matching, stanford-nlp

I am using Python3 and want to do pattern matching on dependency graphs. I tried to use Semgrex tool from StanfordCoreNLP as shown in the example code below:

```
import requests
url = "http://localhost:9000/semgrex"
request_params = {"pattern": "{pos:NN}"}
text = "This is just a simple example"
r = requests.post(url, data = text, params=request_params)
print (r.json())
```

However, I kept getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#81>", line 1, in <module>
    print (r.json())
  File "C:\Users\Hp2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 892, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Hp2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 319, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "C:\Users\Hp2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 339, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "C:\Users\Hp2\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug with the current code when your first request is to tokensregex, semgrex, or tregex.  The timeout is too short for semgrex, so it times out before the initial pipeline is built.  One way to fix this is to initially make a standard request, and then after the pipeline loads and responds to that, it should work for future semgrex requests.

I have increased the timeout in the current code base for initial requests to account for the time to build a default pipeline, so you can also just get the latest code and run the server with that.  Info about building the latest code is here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/download.html

The code changes should be live within the next 20 minutes.

Comment: Info on starting the Java server: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/corenlp-server.html

Comment: Thanks. I just downloaded the latest code, ran the server with it and increased the timeout: `java -mx4g -cp "*" edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.StanfordCoreNLPServer -port 9000 -timeout 900000000`. Then I tried my python code above but I am still getting the same error. How can I initially make a standard request in my python code to fix that?

Comment: The timeout at the command line is not the timeout I am referring to, it's a timeout hard-coded in the code.  Did you build the latest code from GitHub or are you referring to Stanford CoreNLP 3.8.0?

Comment: I downloaded the Stanford CoreNLP 3.8.0 from the command line:
`wget http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/stanford-corenlp-full-2017-06-09.zip`

Comment: The fix I made is in the latest code from GitHub it is not in Stanford CoreNLP 3.8.0